# Can`t round the corners of the button

Tags: android, imagebutton

I wrote the code below, but my ImageButton still has sharp corners. Maybe I don`t know something, if you know that, please, tell me.

**My View**

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/bottle"
    android:src="@drawable/bottle"
    android:background="@drawable/rouncorners"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"/>
```

**Drawable xml file :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<corners android:radius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I tested on my Studio with my launcher icon as the image inside and I got the required result. Here's the entire xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/bottle"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:background="@drawable/rouncorners"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And the xml to be placed in the drawable file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke android:width="3dip" android:color="@color/profile_cover" />
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
 </shape>
```

The result was as follows:

[image: Resultant image]

This is what you're looking for right? It have rounded corner and an image inside.

Comment: No, ImageView, TextView all the same result.

Comment: in first case sharp corners, in second case button doesn`t create, just empty space.

Comment: @ded-logoped Check my answer now. I tested on my studio and made sure it works.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code and clear project and run, Hope it is display.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">
<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="@color/your_color" />
<solid android:color="@color/your_color" /></shape>
```

Comment: You can change to Imageview and Implement background shape and src to image. Hope this is working fine !!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue (it was with a Button), I had created a drawable shape with corners, stroke, solid etc but although I could see the button correctly displayed in the Preview, I wouldn't see it in the actual app. I haven't figured out why, but the solution was to set the drawable as the background of the button *programmatically* like so
 `someButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_rounded_corners);`